# I have a WCF application works fine in all Windows 7 versions except Home edition. Is there anything more to do with it to invoke the WCF?

Tags: wcf, windows-7

I have a WCF works fine in all Windows 7 versions except Home edition. Is there anything more to do with Windows 7 Home editions to invoke the WCF ?

Comment: what does your wcf application do ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Unsupported Scenarios of WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738624.aspx)

> For various reasons, Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) does not
>   support some specific security scenarios. For example, Windows XP Home
>   Edition does not implement the SSPI or Kerberos authentication
>   protocols, and therefore WCF does not support running a service with
>   Windows authentication on that platform